# Ways to guess if C2DM is connected

Tags: android, google-talk, android-c2dm

I'm trying to place a best guess estimate as to whether C2DM messages can be received.

I've created an application that relies on pushing information to a phone while it is physically inaccessible. I understand that C2DM isn't guaranteed delivery, but I'd at least like to know when the delivery of a message is even possible; when it isn't we fall back to our own push service (and can actually tell when we're connected).

I've noticed C2DM on android will still issue auth tokens even when there is not a logged in google account; messages still seem to be delivered in this instance even though it's stated that they shouldn't be. If GTalk isn't connected (firewall or other reasons), no response at all is returned when requesting an auth token. Auth tokens are returned to the application when the phone is in airplane mode. This means it's not as simple as checking if an internet is available. I can't find a reliable way of checking if GTalk is logged in.

Again, I don't need to *guarantee* the delivery of messages, but I'd at least like to know if delivery is even *possible*. Does anyone have interesting solutions?

Comment: Just need clarification, you want to know server side if you can contact the phone?

Comment: Either or would be ok... But main goal was to be able to tell on the phone if it was connected, so that I could open my own TCP connection if necessary.

Comment: Afaik c2dm relies on market so if you can access market and you have been validated ofcourse, you should be clear.

Comment: Being validated and being able to *actively* receive messages are not the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLM4LajwDVc), it's a Google I/O talk about C2DM, how to use it and how it works. AFAIK, you can't know if it's connected or not. Probably most of the time they don't even know (until they have to deliver a message and fail).

However, it is highly recommended (in the video as well) that you do not send important data through C2DM (as messages can get lost). The service should only be used as a "network tickle" (with a footprint as small as possible). Your application should be woken up by this tickle and it should start fetching the information it needs **itself**.

Now, if you implement it this way, it should be easy to implement a polling mechanism. Since you already separated the "tickle" from the actual information retrieval, you can just trigger the retrieval every once in a while if there's no tickle.

Something you can do to check whether C2DM is connected is something like a ping:

1. Send message to phone via C2DM
2. The app receives (or doesn't receive) the message and sends a "pong" back to your server
3. The server waits for the "pong" for a predetermined amount of time (1-2 minutes, I'd say) before marking the device as "offline".

**Edit:** relying on GTalk is not feasible. GTalk relies on C2DM just like your app, it doesn't have anything "extra". Also, GTalk is not present on all devices. I'm not sure how the GTalk app determines whether it's offline or not (it's not open source, unfortunately), but I'd guess it just tries to ping a server and fails.

Comment: I've already done exactly what you describe, but I'd like to do *more*. Looking at logcat dumps, GTalk knows *exactly* when it's connected, and sends keep-alives every 300 seconds. There's just no way for me to interface with GTalk to ask whether or not it's connected. GTalk does not rely on C2DM, it relies on Jabber, and C2DM messages are bundled into the XMPP specification and delivered over GTalk. Also, if GTalk isn't present, then C2DM will not work (this I can actually detect and account for).

Comment: How do you know C2DM doesn't work if GTalk is not present? Have you encountered devices that lack GTalk and C2DM? I'm not sure it's guaranteed that if GTalk is not present then C2DM is not available. I can't watch that talk again (it's 1 hour), but from what I remember they said all their apps (Gmail, GTalk, etc.) use the same C2DM connection for push messages. The same connection that your application ultimately uses. GTalk might connect to Jabber when you launch the app / when the screen is on, but that's separate from C2DM.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "C2DM messages are bundled into the XMPP specification and delivered over GTalk". AFAIK (and I might be wrong), C2DM is completely separated / different than XMPP or Jabber. And GTalk is just the app.

Comment: Further inspection reveals its not really reliant on GTalk, but rather GSF... but again I'm not looking for a guarantee of delivery, just some heuristics to use to determine if delivery is possible. I think the reason google doesn't offer guarenteed delivery is because of the added overhead required to ensure the phone received it. Ex. No network connection -> 0% chance of delivery. Other metrics can improve my *guess*.

Comment: It depends on *where* you need this information as well. If you need it on the server side, I think the only way of knowing is via the ping method described in my answer. If you need it on the device, yes, you can do some other stuff such as check for a network connection and try a simple request as well (such as an HTTP request to google.com, or your own domain) and see if you get anything.

Comment: I want to know on the phone only. HTTP is a decent solution, but HTTP and C2DM are over different ports so doesn't really account for firewalls.

Comment: You can set up a simple HTTP server on port 5228 (the same port C2DM uses) and try a request there. Seems like a pretty big headache though.

Comment: Need to use a TCP server rather than HTTP to be a bit more accurate, since some firewalls filter the traffic differently, but yeah a good point. +1 for overall good advice.

Comment: Yup, good point. However, AFAIK (note that this is not my territory at all here, I might be wrong) C2DM is done over SSL. And when you do something over SSL, the actual protocol is not filterable by any firewalls (because it can't be read). In which case you could just setup an HTTPS server on port 5228, to simplify things.

Comment: Huawei phones don't have GTalk installed and C2DM doesn't work, too

Answer (score 7):

No that is impossible.As you device authenticated once and generate registration ID and send to third party server(As you already know).Now your work is over once the device has been registered.So Wait for message either you got or not(No guarantee of delivering message as C2DM used UDP Protocol ).

**Alternative Solution**

Although its impossible to check from Google side directly as i mentions above,But if you have any urgency to check connection from your phone
then you can take approach like this

Step 1): Make one Web service to check connection

Step 2): Call this web service from application that will command to server to send push notification for checking purpose.

Step 3): Now from server side,server will immediately send push notification for particular device(FROM which it get command)

Step 4): Now if you got push notification that means you are still connected to C2DM.

this will not take much time.But follow it only when checking connection is urgent and it is on user

Comment: I know it's not possible to check a connection, but it is possible to see if a connection is *likely*. Mostly looking for any data that can hint towards such.

Comment: I think no Because in this protocol is used that is not responsible for delivery assurance of any packet and it establish a connection when it need to send a message.So i think its not possible to check connection as there is no connection all the time

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit naive as I am not an active C2DM user, but wouldn't it be possible to read

> /proc/net/netstat

and see if there are any active TCP connections. If there aren't any, then C2DM can't possibly be working. You could also make this technique more versatile by forming a C2DM whitelist that you would expect to find (or maybe its possible to filter on a special C2DM port?)

Comment: Can't try this yet but will soon, sounds promising!

Answer (score 0):

If the device is inaccessible, even your fallback push messaging system wouldn't work. The C2DM doesn't guarantee that it will deliver your message, but the event of non-delivery would be very rare. So would be the case with any other service. The best workaround that you could have is to poll your server to check if you have any new messages that hasn't been delivered yet. I am assuming that your application is such that it's very important not to miss even a single message in 500 or may be 1000. In that case, you could implement a hybrid of push and pull.

Comment: Something I feared, but that ruins the push methodology. Still hoping there's an abstract solution that doesn't involve a poll.

Comment: Well, remember... C2DM's purpose isn't to deliver messages when there's no network connectivity available. C2DM's purpose is to allow the phone to freely go to sleep instead of busy-polling the server for activity, confident that C2DM will allow the server to wake up the phone and trigger intentional communication between the phone and server when it happens. Metaphorically, C2DM is a doorbell (or the network equivalent of an IRQ), NOT a message delivery mechanism in its own right. It wakes up the phone and lets your application know that something interesting has happened on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a little with C2Dm, I've created my own push 3rd party server .
I've implemented a little logic based oh C2DM http response code to know if a push message was sent or not . 
Here is some of the code I used  :

```
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED || responseCode == HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN) {

        LOGGER.warn("Unauthorized - need token");

        return false;
    }
```

here I'm almost sure that the push message was sent from the c2dm servers because I've got an id ont the response:

```
if (responseParts[0].equals("id")) {
        LOGGER.info("Successfully sent data message to device: " + responseLine);

        return true;
    }
```

I've used other methods to get other result codes from Google if you want I can post them.I hope that I've helped you a bit .

Comment: I'm also doing the same on the back end, but the ID from the response only verifies that the google server received the message, not whether the phone will. C2DM offers **no** guarantee of delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to determine in ADVANCE whether there's any chance a push attempt will work, but I can think of a fairly straightforward way to verify receipt (but not queueing for future delivery via C2DM) -- just complete the message loop.

Remember, C2DM's main benefit is that it allows notifications when then phone is asleep and nominally offline. Once your application gets the notification, there's little to stop you from waking up the phone at that point, bringing up the network, and sending a confirmation. I don't think you'd even have to request "keep phone awake" permissions, because I believe the mere act of having registered for C2DM notifications and receiving one is sufficient to wake up the phone and allow the app to continue running normally (at least, long enough to bring up the network and send the confirmation).

While you're at it, you should keep track of confirmations that happen LONG after you expected them to be a lost cause. If you see more than a few, you might have to alter the resend strategy.

The only real-world edge case where this might fail is if you had users who bent over backwards to disable data while leaving voice/SMS enabled (I'm pretty sure C2DM uses 4 bytes of the response datagram sent when a phone polls for incoming calls & text messages that were originally set aside for RIM, then later repurposed for Apple and Google).

Comment: This was an idea I had as well, the problem is this method only informs me of the last time a connection was made to the server. It's practically useless to me because it's impossible to tell if the connection still exists without sending another message.

Answer (score 0):

try to shut down all network connections and reconnect again. if you will get an registration id, then you can receive messages.

Comment: Registration ID is sent even when there's no network connection... not entirely sure how it's generated and this behaviour seems weird. Registrations are meant to be persistent and are you're not supposed to re-register.

Answer (score 0):

Something related to the long running C2DM-connection that is used to deliver the triggers:

- On WLAN it sends a heartbeat every 15 minutes.
- On mobile networks the timeout is 28 mintes.

28 Minutes might be to long, depening on the hardware your mobile carrier uses, 2g/3g repeaters in garages, etc.

You can get lots of information about the connection by opening the Google Talk Service Monitor Application: http://www.honeytechblog.com/monitor-google-talk-service-android/

Dial: *#*#8255#*#*

Theres also a button that sends a heartbeat right now and resets the timeout.

If you want to ensure (on the client side) that c2dm-messages can be received at a given time, your best bet is to re-send the heartbeat. This can be done programmatically - only on rooted devices though. I might release an apk to the market sometime that does exactly that.