# Android How to disable push notifications?

Tags: android

Is there any way to check/manage the push notifications (C2DM or from other service) is available for the Android phone or its based on application to application and have to manage in application only.

Regards,
Android_IT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Yes you can disable it..
```

Let me explain how? When you want `push notification` from server then you have to register your device. So same as there is option of`unregistered`if you do not want `push notification` anymore.So simply check if your device is already registered then unregistered your device.

But next and most important thing which i think you want. `In android device there is not option explicitly to stop push notifications.`So you have to implement by using code.

On this topic many people have discuss so i am giving you reference.Go through it May this help you

[Click me for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899359/ways-to-guess-if-c2dm-is-connected/7966646#7966646)

Answer (score 5):

If your push messages are `wap push messages` and they are not from your facebook/gmail account, it definitely comes from your other installed application. To detect from which application it comes from just install free app called `Airpush detector` and detect which apps send push messages and uninstall them.
Here is [link for Airpush dector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en)

Comment: this is a wrong answer, and it has to be put as comments only

Answer (score 4):

i too have been receiving annoying push messages on my samsung galaxy s7562. what i did to stop it... i just go to the messaging-settings-push message settings and i simply unchecked the "receive push message from network"...hope this will help.